# Cannot use geometry manager grid inside - Need to use .grid() and not .pack()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

unfortunately I have spent way too long on this issue. Here is the simplified version of my code;

```
class MyApp(Frame):
    
    def createWidgets(self):     
   
        btn_dir = Button(self, text = "Select Directory", command = self.MyDir)
        start_date = Entry(self, width = 20)
        end_date = Entry(self, width = 20)
        
        btn_dir.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        start_date.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        end_date.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.work_dir = ''
        
    def MyDir(self):
        self.work_dir = askdirectory(title = 'Select Working Directory Folder')
        myLabel = Label(text = self.work_dir)
        #myLabel.pack()
        myLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    
    
    def error(self, date1, date2, path_1):
...... #something happens
    
    
    def __init__(self, master): 
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()


root = Tk()
app = MyApp(root)
app.mainloop()
```

I understand that I cannot have `grid()` and `pack()` under the same root window and I also understand the issue is resolved using .pack() however I would like that label in a specific location `grid(row = 0, column = 1)`.

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like the frame is packed, Do you want the widgets to be inside `root` or frame? If its frame, then pass  `self` as the first argument to every required widget.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @CoolCloud, i tried passing `self ` as the first argument to every widget and still received the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to place every widget inside the frame, so you have to pass in `self` as the parent of EVERY widget. You did not pass in `self` for the `Label` and hence the error.

```
def MyDir(self):
    self.work_dir = askdirectory(title = 'Select Working Directory Folder')
    myLabel = Label(self,text = self.work_dir) # Use self
    myLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
```

Or the other solution is to remove `self.pack()` and use `self.grid(row=0,column=0)` instead.